# Accessing values of a map that containing a vector pair

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, std-pair

I declared a map that contains a vector pair like

```
typedef vector<pair<string,int>> vectorPair;
map<string,vectorPair> mapName;
```

I've been trying to iterate through the map with an iterator and I'm confused as to how I access the vector pair from Iterator->first or Iterator->second. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Show the code that is  trying to iterate through the map

Answer (score 1):

Here's a neat and tidy way to iterate through the map:

```
for (auto x : mapName)
{
    vectorPair& vp = x.second;        // or auto&
    ...
}
```

Live demo at [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/u6bnYkOOVjWsBckq)

Answer (score 0):

I do not exactly know what you are trying to achieve, but I assume you have a construct that looks something like this:

```
for(auto i = mapName.begin(); i != mapName.end(); i++)
{

}
```

and in that loop you simply want to access the vector? That would be done using `i->second`. If you do not like that syntax you could always use a reference (something like `auto &vec = i->second` and then only use `vec` afterwards).

If you want to iterate over the pairs in the vector itself, you would need to use something like this:

```
for(auto i = mapName.begin(); i != mapName.end(); i++)
{
    for(auto j = i->second.begin(); j != i->second.end(); j++)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: If your compiler has `auto` available, then it also has [ranged-based `for` loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) available, so you should use that instead of using iterators directly: `for(auto &v : mapName) { for(auto &p : v.second) { /* use p as needed ...*/ } }`